# Marker will not trigger event on click - Google Maps Javascript API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a array containing all the markers of the map. I have no trouble placing them on the map even using MarkerClusterer with them. addListener for the MarkerClusterer works just fine, but I just simply can't get marker addListener to trigger the event. Here is the actual code:

```
function initializeMap(markerArray) {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 21,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var length = markerArray.length,
    element = null;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i = i + 2) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markerArray[i],markerArray[i+1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        title:'Click to zoom'
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'onclick', function() {
    alert("I have been clicked");
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    alert("I have been clicked");
});
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have a click listener on your last marker (at least in the code you posted).

[working markerclusterer example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html)

Comment: Wow, thanks geocodezip! I had a completely wrong understanding of how addListener works. I just put all the markers in array and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there any way to add zoom on click, now it is not zooming to the location